# what is UserQuery in Linqpad?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, dbcontext, linqpad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LINQPad error: ‘UserQuery’: cannot derive from sealed type ‘My.Entity.Framework.CustomDataContext’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915805/linqpad-error-userquery-cannot-derive-from-sealed-type-my-entity-framework)

i am running this query in LINQPad 4 with C# Expression as language

```
from t in typeof(UserQuery).GetProperties()
where t.Name == "tablename"
from c in t.GetValue(this,null).GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetFields()
select c.Name
```

but when i use this query in C# web application it gives error no reference of UserQuery

```
var result = from t in typeof(UserQuery).GetProperties()
             where t.Name == "tablename"
             from c in t.GetValue(this,null).GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetFields()
             select c.Name
```

and vs 2012 intellisense didnt picked any reference of it. please tell me which library reference is needed to be added for execution of above query or which class object is needed to be created for referencing ??

currently i m using EF 5.0 and DbContext object which is generated when creating EF data model by Database First Approach

i prefer answer which related to DbContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to query the properties of a typed data context.

To get this working in Visual Studio, replace UserQuery with the name of your typed DataContext.

Answer (score 4):

`UserQuery` is the class LINQPad uses as a container for the code you enter into its textfield. As such, it is only available to code you run in LINQPad.

Comment: so any way to run above LINQ query in my C# Web Application?

Comment: @NewbieFreak: I don't even know what that code is supposed to do...

Comment: Is there any way to use the UserQuery object out of LINQ Pad?